# In uploading device code in the getting started exercise, keep failing in multiple attempts

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, iot-devkit, mxchip, iot-workbench

In this step of the "Getting start" guide:

> 8. Click F1 again, type and select Azure IoT Device Workbench: Upload Device Code

It starts to compile and upload the code to DevKit.
I get the error below. Any idea? Thanks.

> from C:\Users\ayung\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\AZ3166\hardware\stm32f4\1.6.1\cores\arduino\httpserver\app_httpd.cpp:33:
>           C:\Users\ayung\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\AZ3166\hardware\stm32f4\1.6.1\system/platform/wait_api.h:21:2: warning: #warning wait_api.h has been replaced by mbed_wait_api.h, please update to mbed_wait_api.h [since mbed-os-5.3] [-Wcpp]
>   #warning wait_api.h has been replaced by mbed_wait_api.h, please update to mbed_wait_api.h [since mbed-os-5.3]
>   In file included from C:\Users\ayung\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\AZ3166\hardware\stm32f4\1.6.1\cores\arduino/system/mbed.h:95:0, 
>   from C:\Users\ayung\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\AZ3166\hardware\stm32f4\1.6.1\cores\arduino/EEPROMInterface.h:7,
>   from C:\Users\ayung\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\AZ3166\hardware\stm32f4\1.6.1\cores\arduino\httpserver\app_httpd.cpp:33:        C:\Users\ayung\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\AZ3166\hardware\stm32f4\1.6.1\system/platform/sleep.h:21:2: warning: #warning sleep.h has been replaced by mbed_sleep.h, please update to mbed_sleep.h [since mbed-os-5.3] [-Wcpp]
>   #warning sleep.h has been replaced by mbed_sleep.h, please update to mbed_sleep.h [since mbed-os-5.3]
>   
> In file included from C:\Users\ayung\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\AZ3166\hardware\stm32f4\1.6.1\cores\arduino/system/mbed.h:96:0,
>   
> from C:\Users\ayung\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\AZ3166\hardware\stm32f4\1.6.1\cores\arduino/EEPROMInterface.h:7,
>   
> from C:\Users\ayung\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\AZ3166\hardware\stm32f4\1.6.1\cores\arduino\httpserver\app_httpd.cpp:33:
>       C:\Users\ayung\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\AZ3166\hardware\stm32f4\1.6.1\system/platform/rtc_time.h:21:2: warning: #warning rtc_time.h has been replaced by mbed_rtc_time.h, please update to mbed_rtc_time.h [since mbed-os-5.3] [-Wcpp]
>   
> #warning rtc_time.h has been replaced by mbed_rtc_time.h, please update to mbed_rtc_time.h [since mbed-os-5.3]
>   
> C:\Users\ayung\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\AZ3166\tools\arm-none-eabi-gcc\5_4-2016q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-ar: unable to rename 'core\core.a'; reason: File exists
>   
> exit status 1
>   
> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
>   
> [Error] Exit with code=1

Made sure board settings are correct in VSCode and in Arduino

Comment: I have seen similar failures before and the only way I found to resolve it was by reinstalling the Arduino IDE. Can you give this a try?

Comment: I re-installed Arduino IDE and updated firmware. Got same error.  Then re-installed VSCode. Now cannot install board in VSCode. VSCode gives error: [Starting] Install package - AZ3166...
Loading configuration...
Initializing packages...
Preparing boards...
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at processing.app.BaseNoGui.onBoardOrPortChange(BaseNoGui.java:679)
 at processing.app.Base.onBoardOrPortChange(Base.java:1312)
 at processing.app.Base.<init>(Base.java:282)
 at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:151)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
[Error] Exit with code=255

Comment: It seems the Arduino IDE was still not installed correctly. After uninstall Arduino, could you also remove the cached files in  %Program Files%\Arduino and %User Profile%\AppData\Local\Arduino15. Then install Arduino IDE again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and my searches only found this and the FAQ where I found "Failed to install Arduino Package for IoT DevKit" but it was not my issue.  That reference was about a corrupted install <https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/faq/>.

After several attempts this is what worked for me:

1. Uninstalled the Extension pack from VSCode
2. Uninstalled all of the Azure extension packs I have in VSCode.
3. I forgot to update the settings.json
4. Quit VSCode and went for a cup of coffee
5. Restarted VSCode
6. Re-installed the Arduino extension
7. Press F1
8. Launch Arduino Board Manager
9. I watched the Output window and it went through without a problem! (This is where I was getting the error before)
10. Installed Azure IoT Tools
11. Went back to the Arduino Board Manager, entered AZ and it found it!
12. I installed the latest version of MXChip - Microsoft Azure IoT Developer Kit by Microsoft

Hope this helps you.  Good Luck